# Django Inline Formsets using custom form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using inline formsets.

My model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 40, 'rows': 4}),
        }
```

In my views.py I made the form from the AuthorForm like so

```
form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
```

But I also made a formset for the Books

```
InlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Books)
```

I cannot pass in a BooksForm with widgets, so how do I add a textarea widget to the book details.

Is it even possible? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        widgets = {
            'details': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 40, 'rows': 4}),
        }


InlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, form=BookForm)
```

## Update by Wtower

> This is great. Specifically for widgets, as of Django 1.6 there is a widgets parameter for inlineformset_factory

Sounds like you can now call

```
inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, widgets={'details': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 40}))
```

Comment: Glad it actually worked! I couldn't easily find any docs either, I just looked at the source.

Comment: This is great. Specifically for widgets, as of Django 1.6 there is a `widgets` parameter for `inlineformset_factory`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30192034/940098

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i have understand your question: do you want Book.details rendered as a textarea?

If so, just use a TextField instead a CharField.

```
class Author(models.Model):
   description = models.TextField()
```

Comment: this is correct for a textfield, but im looking for somkething that also does radio buttons, checkboxes etc. Was trying to keep my example simple. Thanks