# Django: How to change a field widget in a Inline Formset

Tags: python, django, forms, inline-formset

I am new to Django and I think I am missing this in the docs. 
The problem is that in inline-formset I dont declare a form, just pass two models to construct it.

 I want to know how can I change a widget of a single field using inline formset?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Inline Formsets using custom form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106327/django-inline-formsets-using-custom-form)

Answer (score 21):

[As of Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#specifying-widgets-to-use-in-the-form-with-widgets), you can use the `widgets` parameter of `modelformset_factory` in order to customize the widget of a particular field:

```
AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Author, widgets={
    'name': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20})
})
```

and [therefore](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#specifying-widgets-to-use-in-the-inline-form) the same parameter for `inlineformset_factory` (which uses `modelformset_factory`):

```
AuthorInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, fields=['name'], widgets={
    'name': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20})
})
```

Comment: kindly could you update your answer to new versions 3.* ?

Comment: I've resolved with inlineformset_factory(MotherModel, ChildModel, form=MyForm, extra=1)

Comment: How do you add widget for the first form, and not the extra ones?

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of customizing one field using formfield_callback:

```
def formfield_callback(field):
    if isinstance(field, models.ChoiceField) and field.name == 'target_field_name':
        return fields.ChoiceField(choices = SAMPLE_CHOICES_LIST, label='Sample Label')
    return field.formfield()

FormSet = inlineformset_factory(ModelA, ModelB, extra=1, formfield_callback = formfield_callback)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a form and update widget in the `Meta` class. Look at [Overriding the default field types or widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But how to specify a form to be used in a inline-formset?

Comment: @nsbm, you can define a model form and create `formset` (not `modelformset` from it.

Answer (score 2):

you can subclass the formset and override the add_fields method. This worked for me and I am using Django 1.5 :( .

```
AuthorInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book)
class AuthorFormSet(AuthorInlineFormSet):
        def add_fields(self, form, index):
            super(ReferenceForm,self).add_fields(form,index)
            form.fields["name"] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old thread. Now we can do this using django ModelForm itself.

Add your model form in `forms.py` with widgets.

**forms.py**

```
class QAForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = QA
        fields = ['question', 'answer', 'status']
        widgets = {
            'question': widgets.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'rows': 3,
                    'cols': 40
                }
            ),
            'answer': widgets.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'rows': 3,
                    'cols': 40
                }
            ),
            'status': widgets.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-select'
                }
            )
        }
```

pass it using `from` parameter for your `modelformset_factory` like following in your `views.py`

**views.py**

```
QAFormSet = modelformset_factory(
                                 models.QA,
                                 fields=["question", "answer", "status"],
                                 form=QAForm
                                )
```